# Fill assoc array in PHP with variables

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to fill an array in php with variables, but it's not working out at all. I'm using JSON and Javascript..

Anyway, here's the PHP code Javascript makes a call to.

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];

    $json = '{
    "userdata": [
        {
            "first":"$username"
        },
        {
            "first":"Lester"
        },
        {
            "first":"Mannix"
        }
    ]
}';
echo $json;

?>
```

Now, the problem is, what I get back to Javascript is "$username", in plain text, not the variable's value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $username has not been recognized as a variable. Use "first":"'.$username.'"

Comment: Consider using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), unless you *really* don't need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't recognized in single quotes [<sup>[doc]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

```
$json = '{
    "userdata": [
        {
            "first":"'.$username.'"
        },
        {
            "first":"Lester"
        },
        {
            "first":"Mannix"
        }
    ]
}';
```

Comment: @macek: I have just corrected the error from OP. Requirement for json_encode is `(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)`

Comment: @Martin: You can use json_encode on a lower version of php just download http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/

Answer (score 0):

USE [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)!

```
$json = array('userdata' => array(
  array('first'=>'foo'),
  array('first'=>'bar'),
  array('first'=>'bof')
));

echo json_encode($json);
```

Output

```
{"userdata":[{"first":"foo"},{"first":"bar"},{"first":"bof"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way of creating a JSON array

```
$json = array(
            "userdata" => array(
                   array("first" => $_POST['username']),
                   array("first" => "Lester"),
                   array("first" => "Mannix"),
             )
         );
echo json_encode($json);
```